# Is it possible to check for overlapping dates on distinct rows in SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql

Let's say I have the following data:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  id|  StartDate|    EndDate|
+----+-----------+-----------+
| ABC| 2020-01-01| 2021-01-22|
| ABC| 2021-01-23| 2021-01-31|
| DEF| 2020-02-01| 2021-02-17|
| DEF| 2021-02-15| 2021-02-28|
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

how could I filter out the id's ABC which don't have overlapping dates whilst maintaining visibility of the problematic overlap (for data quality reasons) for DEF?

The end result could look something like:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  id|  StartDate|    EndDate|
+----+-----------+-----------+
| DEF| 2020-02-01| 2021-02-17|
| DEF| 2021-02-15| 2021-02-28|
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: You could use CTE and sort on the start date and then use the values from the previous record to see if there is overlap. See [Lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hopefully the table has a PK. Otherwise what if two rows are totally equal?

Comment: @Serg if two rows are completely equal for the purposes of this query then any after the first are ignored, but I see your point